# Find a list of Patterns in a input stream

Tags: algorithm

Suppose you have an input character stream (StreamReader) and you have a list of pattens like ABCAS, ASGKT. KHTSD etc.
You need to read the stream one by one character and you need to keep count on number of each pattern found so far and when EOF occures just print all the patterns along with count.

Example:
Input String:   011100010 
Pattern 1:  011

Pattern 2: 010

Output: 
   011 => 1 
   010 => 1

Comment: This is a typical application for [lex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_(software)).

Comment: use lex in c. it is it's very basic functionality.
check out : https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-l.html it is very big example.. but you can read and understand

Answer (score 1):

There are existing tools for solving this problem. They are called *lexers*, and on of the most well-known example is *lex*, mentioned in the comments.

However, if you need to implement it yourself, [Aho-Corasick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) algorithm does the thing. Given a set of strings *S* = *s_1, ..., s_k* of total length *L*, it builds a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) on these strings and makes an automaton based on this trie. Now you feed your input string into this automaton. At any time it is capable of telling you the set of strings from *S* that end at current position, with time proportional to the number of such strings.

For example, if *S = {"aba", "bababa", "ba", "abacaba"}* and your have inputted the string *rabacaba*, the output of the algorithm will be *{0, 2, 3}* (the indices of the strings which end at the last fed position).

Having such structure, maintaining occurred strings and their count is straightforward: just make a query to the structure after each character of the stream.